# Public maven repo for mongodb-async-driver

Tags: mongodb-java

I've found the mongo drive written by Allan Bank (http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/index.html), really useful.

Does anyone know if it exists in any public maven repo I can reference from my another public project?

Downloading the Jar doesn't cut it when building in another open source project using cloudbees cloud Jenkins.

Comment: You could add it to your own repo (Nexus, Artifactory, whatever you use)

Comment: I am using public maven repo. I have an open source project that relies on public repos only so adding to my own repo isn't an option as I don't have one.